# Flutter plugin for asdf can't find jq?

Tags: flutter, asdf

I installed the Flutter asdf plugin and added flutter to my `.tool-versions` file:

```
golang 1.18.6
nodejs 18.3.0
flutter 3.3.9
```

But am getting errors that the plugin can't find `jq`:

```
~/.asdf/plugins/flutter/bin/install: line 25: jq: command not found
~/.asdf/plugins/flutter/bin/install: line 26: jq: command not found
~/.asdf/plugins/flutter/bin/install: line 27: [: -gt: unary operator expected 
Cannot find the download url for the version: 3.3.9
```

Investigating, I see that `jq` is bundled with the flutter plugin, so adding `~/.asdf/plugins/flutter/bin` to my `PATH` fixes the problem.

I'm rolling this out for other devs and this extra step seems unnecessary. Am I missing something, or is adding the plugin path to the dev's `PATH` necessary?

Answer (score 1):

First installing the `jp`

```
sudo apt install -y jq
```

Next try again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).